# Usage of "neither" in this example?

Tags: conjunctions, negation

This is my sentence:

> The system has no value for neither *Weight*, *Height*, nor *Water Temperature*  properties.

I feel something wrong in the sentence, could you help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using it correctly

> **neither** ... **nor** ...

is the pattern used as the negative of

> **either** ... **or** ...

However, your sentence has a double negative

> **no** ... **neither** ...

you could reformulate it as

> The system has no value for **either** Weight, Height, **or** Water Temperature properties.
>   **Neither** Weight, Height, **nor** Water Temperature properties can be measured by the system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's correct to use another negative in a neither clause. The  sentence should be formed as follows:

> The system has no value for Weight, nor for Height, nor for Water Temperature properties.

OR

The system has value neither for Weight, nor for Height, nor for Water Temperature properties.

OR

The system has no value for Weight, height or Water Temperature properties.

Comment: They won't wait for you, nor for me, nor for anybody (The Free Dictionary).